# How does a Hypervisor synchronize time between Host and Guest VM?

Tags: time, synchronization, virtualization, virtual-machine

I read [this](http://prutser.wordpress.com/2009/02/08/why-does-my-linux-virtual-machine-lose-time/) blog:

> After conducting a bit of research I
>   discovered that this is caused by the
>   fact that the default Linux kernel
>   runs at a 1000Hz internal clock
>   frequency and that VMware is unable to
>   deliver the clock interrupts on time
>   without losing them. This means that
>   some clock interrupts are lost without
>   notice to the Linux kernels which
>   assumes each interrupt marks 1/1000th
>   of a second. So each clock interrupt
>   that gets lost makes the clock fall
>   behind a 1/1000th of a second.

Now, my question is, how does the **hypervisor sync time internally** if the hypervisor is capable of handling the clock interrupts?

Because when say (scaled up example, not real world): its 19:10:22 on Host, till it propagates to the guest, it will be 19:10:23 on the host.

I understand this is a hard problem, but I guess you need to slow the time from the VMs prespective. How is that achieved?

[VMWare timekeeping](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf)

Comment: It's not a serverfault question, it's the internals of a virtual machine.

Comment: Doesn't the PDF you link to answer your question?

Comment: the vmware paper talks more about vmware specific implementation and technology and less about the concept behind that (the whys).

Comment: I guess I don't understand your question then. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: umm, which page/excerpt in the pdf do you think describes this question? I need to understand what methodology is used to sync time (which is virtually impossible).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypervisor does not synchronize the clocks. It is software running in the guest VM that keeps the clocks in sync.

From page 15 (with the explanation continuing on through page 19) of your linked PDF:

> There are two main options available for guest operating system clock synchronization: VMware Tools periodic clock synchronization
>   or the native synchronization software that you would use with the guest operating system if you were running it directly on physical
>   hardware. Some examples of native synchronization software are Microsoft W32Time for Windows and NTP for Linux.

The VMware Tools clock sync tool just checks the guest clock against the host clock every so often (probably once per minute) and corrects the guest clock if it's wrong. If the guest clock is off by just a little bit the tool will speed up or slow down the guest clock until it has the correct time (using an API like [`SetSystemTimeAdjustment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724943(v=VS.85).aspx) on Windows or [`adjtime`](http://phpunixman.sourceforge.net/index.php/man/adjtime) on Unix). If you're wondering how the tool accesses the host's clock, there's just an API for it that the VMware tool knows how to use.

Comment: I am not running it on the physical software, so my question is, how does VMWare tools sync work?

Comment: zengr: I updated my answer, but I don't know what "it" is that you're running or what "the physical software" means. I also don't know what you mean by "work". Are you asking what APIs the clock sync tool calls? What algorithms it uses?

Comment: I am sorry for the ambiguity. I am asking what algorithms are used.

Comment: zengr: I already explained the basic algorithm (check once a minute, adjust as necessary) in my answer. Please ask a more detailed question if you want a more detailed answer.